# interactive boolean like in autodesk fusion 360

Tags: modifiers

My friend is considering to invest time in learning Blender, he has a decade experience using 3Dmx/Maya kind of stuff. So here is his question, that I am trying to translate from Russian, and please note I know little about the topic.

Right now only Autodesk fusion 360 seems to support reliable boolean that is able to operate interactively and able to cotrol the transformation between objects, (making the transformation softer/harder). Can blender do that, and if yes, how, where is the documentation or tutorial can be found?

"нужен не глючащий булен, с возможностью интерактивных операций и возможностью управлять переходом между обьектами(делать его плавным\твердым)"

Comment: Boolean is such a ambigous operation that always can make your work a little bit longer. I'm not sure if it's possible in Blender, but I think this can be scripted,and it can be long way to go. If you know that fusion does what you need, and faster, then you can do it there, and export geometry in Blender. Or you might  use a boolen in Blender and then smooth/sharpen that area as needed (model by hand).